# zeromq w/ Electron: Could not locate the bindings file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, zeromq, electron

I'm using Windows 7 x64, nodejs 5.1.0 and Electron 0.35. I followed the instructions from [Electron Quick Start app](https://github.com/atom/electron-quick-start) and then added the line `require("zmq")` to the main.js. At this point, after `npm install zmq --save`, `electron main.js` displays:

`Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:` [list of `zmq.node` paths]

One of the paths tried is actually present in the system, i.e. `node_modules/zmq/build/Release/zmq.node`

If I remove the Electron app code and leave just the `require("zmq")` line in main.js, I can successfully run with `node main.js`. How am I supposed to get rid of the error when running with Electron?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out after reading [Using Native Node Modules](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.35.0/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/). Basically, after each `npm install` of a native package, it needs to be rebuilt with Electron headers by issuing `.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd`.

Comment: i run "npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild" also the ".\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd" but this solution don't work for me ;/